# Ошибка в Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Если понадобятся ещё файлы, то приложу. Были варианты, что нет зависимости Hibernate, я добавил, но ничего не поменялось, в итоге сюда обращаюсь. Думаю, что с библиотеками что-то не так. Был совет про `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.ApiConnect.repos")` Но после него появились ошибка, которая сейчас приложена ниже.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Ошибка:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.postProcess(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:121)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Blacit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/Blacit/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource
```

Мой pom.xml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiConnect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application

```
package com.example.ApiConnect;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.ApiConnect.repos")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что у вас беда с зависимостями...
Попробуйте так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


-<parent>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

<version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>

<relativePath/>

<!-- lookup parent from repository -->


</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>

<artifactId>ApiConnect</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>ApiConnect</name>

<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


-<properties>

<java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>


-<dependencies>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

<scope>runtime</scope>

<optional>true</optional>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>mysql</groupId>

<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

<scope>runtime</scope>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

<scope>test</scope>


-<exclusions>


-<exclusion>

<groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>

<artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>

</exclusion>

</exclusions>

</dependency>

</dependencies>


-<build>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, правда появились новые ошибки. Сделаю новый топик для них.

Comment: не за что. по крайней мере это уже не зависимости))

Answer (score 2):

достаточно зависимости
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
и в проект попадут все необходимые пакеты хибернейт

@EnableJpaRepositories
нужна если путь где лежат репозитории отличается от основного пакета где лежит точка входа в приложение, т.к. он сканирует вглубь

без нее должен все находить

покажи пожалуйста класс репозитория который вызываешь